# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Driver error

Tags: t-sql, text-files, oledb, linked-server

I have a statement that loads data from flat file to a database table, but it throws an error.
The statement that I am using is:

```
INSERT INTO emp_scd(empno,ename,hiredate) 
       SELECT empno,ename,hiredate 
       FROM 
       OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=D:\Data Migration;',
       'SELECT * FROM Output.txt')
```

But it throws an error as follows:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" 
reported an   error. The provider did not give any information about the error.

Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT * FROM Output.txt" for execution
against OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

I have my **Allow inprocess** for **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0** enabled, but still I am getting that error. What could be possible solution for the same? I am not able to find out where I am going wrong.

Please provide some suggestions for the same.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel into SQL Server with Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822576/excel-into-sql-server-with-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0)

Comment: @ling.s - I am not using an Excel, I am using a flat file(.txt).

Comment: Has the statement ever worked or did it just break out of the blue? Check against connection strings here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/

Comment: @ElectricLlama - the statement did work when I was using SQL Server 2008 but when I switched to SQL Server 2012, it is giving me this error. And thanks for the link, seems to contain some useful information.

Comment: And is the new SQL Server in a new server or is it installed on the existing one? Is the new server 32 or 64 bit? was the old server 32 or 64 bit? If it's a new server, did you install the ACE driver? Regardless of whether it is CSV or XLS, you should check the referred post because it could be exactly the same issue - lack of access to the file.

Comment: its on the same server, the old server was 64-bit and so is the new one. the ACE Driver is installed. I am checking the post that you have given.

Comment: To clarify - I meant the post that ling.s made. Do the SQL Server's run under the same service account?