# Client Data into SQL server

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

My client gave data in Excel looking like this:

```
 |  Sno    | Product Name | Product Type  | Supplier
 --------------------------------------------------- 
 | 1       | Mobile       | Gadgets       | Steve
 | 2       | DataCard     | Internet      | Hauwai
```

(more columns and rows)

I designed a separate table for product, type and supplier etc and now I need import the data into SQL Server. I need to replace the product type with the `ID` and supplier name with `ID` in the Excel sheet. How can I do this? The Excel sheet has more columns and rows. Example it has more than 1000 product types.

Comment: @samyi I tried manually..Please provide some suggestion how to do this easier..

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I think of is:

1) Create SSIS Package such as :
      Source( will be excel) > Destination will be Another table name Producttype, Product, Supplier and so on.

```
Create table ProductType(
        ProductTypeID int identity(1,1),
        ProductType varchar(255)
        )


        Create table Product(
        ProductID int  identity(1,1),
        ProductName varchar(255)
        )


        Create table Supplier(
        SupplierID int  identity(1,1),
        SupplierName varchar(255)
        )
```

2) You can do it in Simple package with Source Excel and destination with SQL Server Table.

**EDIT:**

While you dump data into destination table, you have to worry with only Actual fields coming from Excel source. The ID's are Identity field and will be taken care.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-shot process, use [ACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822576/excel-into-sql-server-with-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0):

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\path\to\file.xls','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Another way is opening the xls in Excel and exporting to csv.  Then use [BULK INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)