# Importing Excel File from Sharepoint using SQL Openrowset

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, sharepoint, openrowset

I'm trying to import an excel file using T-SQL/SSMS on our SQL server 2012, using the syntax below:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;
Database=//MyCompanyName.sharepoint.com/sites/MySharePointSiteName/Shared Documents/Report.xlsx',
'SELECT * FROM [form1$]' )
```

I'm getting the (generic) 7399/7303 message:

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The OLE DB provider "MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The 
provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked 
server "(null)".
```

Any ideas why this would be failing?
We normally don't have issues importing local/network files using OPENROWSET.
Has anyone been successful in using the OPENROWSET operation for this purpose?

Here's what I've tried so far:

1) Ensuring the SQL Service account is set to my Windows Login (and rebooted)
2) Ensuring OPENROWSET is configured correctly
3) Ensuring the site/path is accessible
4) Enclosing the path with QUOTES

Comment: Not certain, but it could be the space between the `Shared Documents`. Try putting double quotes around `"//MyCompanyName.sharepoint.com/sites/MySharePointSiteName/Shared Documents/Report.xlsx"` and see if that works

Comment: Could be  a permission issue,is it working for DBA's ? Did you check the link -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822576/excel-into-sql-server-with-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0

Comment: Hi @SS_DBA - Tried that -  No luck

Comment: @VN'sCorner - I've switched the user for the SQL server account over to my own. I obviously have access to the site already. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permission issue.  Can you run this?

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DisallowAdHocAccess', 0
GO



USE [master] 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
GO
```

Also, can you try to set your permissions like this?

[image]

Check out the links below.

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/The-OLE-DB-provider-Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0-for-linked-server-null.aspx

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/11/26/sql-server-ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-for-linked-server-null-returned-message-unspecified-error/

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/12/04/sql-server-the-ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-for-linked-server-null-reported-an-error-access-denied/

I'm guessing it should work after that.  Try those ideas, and feedback.

Comment: Thanks @ash - I did all that - no dice.

Comment: Very weird.  Maybe the file is corrupt.  Can you access this file by any other means?